# Limit/Reset @Environment scope in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my framework, I extend `View` to add some functionality.

```swift
public extension View {
    func popup<PopupContent>(@ViewBuilder popupContent: @escaping () -> PopupContent) -> some View where PopupContent : View {
        LNPopupViewWrapper(popupContent: popupContent) {
            self
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

The result ends up creating a container `UIViewController`, which can present the container view, as well as the popup content. I also provide various modifiers to `View`, to augment the behavior of this container, such as adding a context menu:

```swift
public extension View {
    func popupBarContextMenu<MenuItems>(@ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> MenuItems) -> some View where MenuItems : View {
        return environment(\.popupBarContextMenu, AnyView(menuItems()))
    }
}
```

The environment is then read inside my framework and handled using an `@Environment` property:

```swift
@Environment(\.popupBarContextMenu) var popupBarContextMenu: AnyView?
```

The issue is, if the user creates nested `.popup()`s, the environment propagates deeply into the nested popup.

```
NavitaionView {
    Button("Outer") {
        viewPresented.toggle()
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewPresented, content: {
        Text("Inner").popup {
            InnerPopupContentView()
        }
    })
}.popup {
    OuterPopupContentView()
}.popupBarContextMenu {
    OuterPopupContextMenu()
}
```

The inner popup ends up inheriting the external popup context menu.

My question is, how to create a “barrier” between “layers” of popups, or somehow reset the environment for each `LNPopupViewWrapper`?

SwiftUI itself exposes a very similar `.contextMenu()` modifier, which internally uses `SwiftUI.ContextMenuModifier` rather than an environment modifier, and I wonder how they implement this only for the current view the method is called on? Perhaps Environment is not the right approach, but I don’t see what else I can use.

`SwiftUI.ContextMenuModifier` is “cheating” somehow, by having a `SwiftUI.ViewIdentity` reference, which is somehow used to associate with only one view.

```
SwiftUI.(ContextMenuModifier in $96e558)
----------------------------------------
menuView: A
(generic_type_parameter depth=0 index=0)

id: SwiftUI.ViewIdentity
(struct SwiftUI.ViewIdentity)
```

Comment: Environment value has single storage, later call replaces previous, so because children view are created first the most other parent view resets internal setting. Thus Environment value does not look appropriate for this feature. As far as I understood the scenario it needs direct property injection, so every layer having own member stores own menu.

Comment: @Asperi How to achieve this? The `popupBarContextMenu()` modifier needs to be callable per “layer”, rather than immediately after calling `popup()`. I am not familiar with any “per layer” storage, while Apple is able to cheat through private API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I’ve worked around this issue by creating a “consumer” wrapper, which remembers the first consumer of the environment value, and returns `nil` for other, deeper consumers.

```swift
internal final class LNPopupEnvironmentConsumer<T> {
    private let wrapped: T
    private unowned var consumer: AnyObject? = nil
    
    init?(_ wrapped: T?) {
        guard let wrapped = wrapped else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    }
    
    func consume(_ consumer: AnyObject) -> T? {
        guard self.consumer == nil || self.consumer === consumer else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.consumer = consumer
        return wrapped
    }
}
```

In my `UIHostingController`, I `consume()` the value, and use if a non-`nil` value is returned.

```swift
if let contextMenu = self.currentPopupState.contextMenu?.consume(self) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment is used to send data downstream a hierarchy of views. Would it not make more sense that `popupBarContextMenu` is applied to the content of the popup, instead of the outer view?

If you do that, you actually are sending the data upstream to the parent and you can use preferences. In that case you can actually reset the preference value in the popup, to prevent it affecting other popups.

Unfortunately I do not have an answer that will work for you, as you are trying to pass an `AnyView` to the context menu, which do not work with preferences, as the value needs to be `Equatable`. This might be the reason for Apple's implementation to use `SwiftUI.ViewIdentity`.

If you change from using `AnyView` to some struct that you can make `Equatable`, this is somewhat how the code would look:

```swift
public extension View {
    func popup<PopupContent>(@ViewBuilder popupContent: @escaping () -> PopupContent) -> some View where PopupContent : View {
        LNPopupViewWrapper(popupContent: popupContent) {
            self
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .preference(key: PopupBarContextMenuKey.self, value: nil)
    }
}

public extension View {
    func popupBarContextMenu<MenuItems>(@ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> MenuItems) -> some View where MenuItems : View {
        return preference(key: PopupBarContextMenuKey.self, value: AnyView(menuItems()))
    }
}

NavigationView {
    Button("Outer") {
        viewPresented.toggle()
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewPresented, content: {
        Text("Inner").popup {
            InnerPopupContentView()
        }
    })
}.popup {
    OuterPopupContentView()
        .popupBarContextMenu {
            OuterPopupContextMenu()
        }
}
```

Comment: I found a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72717972/983912

I have modeled my API to be similar to how NavigationView’s API is, and I don’t want to change my design just to fit the bad API Apple has provided, which they themselves hack around.

Comment: For example, if you use the `navigationViewStyle()` modifier, and you have a nested navigation view in a sheet, the style of the inner navigation view is not influenced by the external call.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably fix this by setting popupBarContextMenu to nil at the end of the body in LNPopupViewWrapper.

This would basically “consume” the value and any descendants would get a clean slate.

Comment: I tried that, but then the nil is the one that takes everywhere. It seems with environment modifiers, the first call takes.